# Is this grammatically correct?: "something we thought which might have been lost due to the time and distance"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice

**Here is the context:** Two performers who are based in two different countries are going to carry out a performance together. The two of them cannot see each other often so they thought the senses and physical movements which they developed together might be lost due to the distance and time, but they realised otherwise.

**This is the whole sentence:**
Our senses and physical movements - something we thought which might have been lost due to the time and distance - were still in between us."

I am confused which one is correct:

A) "something we thought which might have been lost due to the time and distance"

B) "something we thought to have been lost due to the time and distance"

C) "something we thought to have been lost over the time and distance"

Comment: _Our senses and physical movements - something we thought would have been lost over time and distance - were still in between us._ I would prefer this variation. Otherwise, I would say, _Our senses and physical movements - something we thought to have lost over time and distance - were still in between us._ But firstly, we need to know more about what meaning does your sentence convey? The sentence construction largely depends on it.

Comment: Hi Dhanishtha, thanks for the comment! Here is the context:
Two performers who are based in two different countries are going to carry out a performance together. The two of them cannot see each other often so they thought the senses and physical movements which they developed together might be lost due to the distance and time, but they realised otherwise.

Comment: **Senses and physical movements** cannot be described as **something**. You need a noun such as **attributes** or **qualities**

Comment: @RonaldSole I see. Could I use "what" instead of "something"?: "what we thought might have been lost due to the time and distance"

Comment: Yes, **what** or **which** - they are slightly different constructions, but both are valid.

Comment: It makes sense if "we thought" is parenthetical, but then it should be set off in commas.

Comment: Just as a note, "Our senses and physical movements were still in between us" doesn't make much sense, since senses and physical movements don't really exist outside of one's body. I think you may need a metaphor to pull this off.

Comment: I would recast the sentence something like this: *We were pleased/relieved/delighted to find that, despite time and distance, we had not lost our rapport of sense and movement.*

Answer (score 0):

It's grammatical, but it doesn't mean much. *Something* is the object of *we thought*; whereas I believe you want *we thought* to be within the relative clause modifying "something":

> something which [we thought might have been lost due to the time and distance]

Your forms with *to have been* are OK as well, but far less natural.

*Over* would do, but it is much less specific than *due to*.

Comment: Hi Colin, thank you for your answer!
Like you suggested, I feel "something which [we thought might have been lost due to the time and distance]" conveys the message best.